# SQL : Get rows with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
id     r_date    time_stamp   licenseid   storeid  deviceid   value
1     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0001       1         0add      52
2     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0002       1         0add      54
3     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0003       1         0add      53
4     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0001       1         0add      54
5     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0002       1         0add      59
6     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0003       1         0add      52
7     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0004       1         0add      55
8     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0001       1         0bdd      63
9     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0002       1         0bdd      52
10    2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0003       1         0cdd      52
11    2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0001       1         0cdd      53
12    2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0002       1         0cdd      52
13    2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0004       1         0cdd      52
```

I need the deviceid for which the device never goes above a certain value and have a count of distinct time_stamp > y. So in the above table I need say those devices which never had a value above 60 and y =1. This should return below.  Since 0add is the only device that is never below 60  and is seen in 2 distinct timestamps.

```
r_date       deviceid   count
2015-06-12    0add         2
```

I have below query to help fetch with the count but how do I add the condition of count>1 and the first condition to only include value that always are below a certain value? I have 2 million rows in the table.

```
SELECT device_id, r_date, COUNT(DISTINCT time_stamp) AS numRows
FROM myTable
GROUP BY device_id, r_date;
```

r_date is of type DATE and time_stamp of type TIME

Comment: I think you will need a subquery of sorts here to first eliminate the devices which never had a value below 60 and then group the rest.

Comment: can you provide a small dump of the relevant dataset, or a fake one but with the structure?

Comment: @VictorNitu  The structure is exactly the same as I have here. Let me know if you need more

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
    SELECT 
        device_id
        , date
        , COUNT(DISTINCT timestamp) AS numRows
    FROM 
        myTable
    WHERE 
        (
        Select 
            COUNT(*) 
        from 
            myTable tmp 
        where 
            tmp.device_id = myTable.device_id 
        where 
            value >= 60
        ) = 0
    GROUP BY device_id, date
    HAVING numRows > 1
```

The subquery will get the count of rows for the current device_id over the selected amount (60) & you want those with count of 0.

Comment: I don't think this will work.  It simply eliminates the value < 60, but still leaves the others.  I think OP requires only devices that never go below 60.

Comment: I misread the first condition, hopefully my edit is correct - I thought the answer was too simple.

Comment: @PaulF Don't think this will help. I want the ones which have count >1 and the ones which never go above 60.

Comment: Does the additional subquery get the correct result

Comment: I have just seen Zafars answer & thought the same.

Comment: @PaulF , Anthony shouldn't the condition be <60 instead of >=60? Also what is the '=0' for at the end of first where?

Comment: See comment below the code - the subquery gets the count of all rows with value bigger than you want. The =0 outside only returns those where the subquery count is zero - ie those that have never gone above 60.

Comment: @PaulF Got It, Testing the query. Taking some time.

Comment: @PaulF what about the date? Will the subquery consider the date while fetching the count of rows. As on one date it might be 0 and the other it may not?

Comment: The subquery ignores the date, but if you do need that taking into account then you could add to the subquery where clause to account for that (_AND DATE(tmp.timestamp)=DATE(myTable.timestamp)_). NOTE use of DATE function to compare only the date, if that is not used then it will compare date & time.

Comment: @PaulF Unfortunately this is timing out on my 2 Million rows table

Comment: Do you have an index on the device_id. I don't think an index on timestamp would have any effect because of the use of the Date function). I'm not sure of any other ways to optimise the query.

Comment: Looking back at your question - I note that r_date & timestamp are separate fields the subquery clause _AND tmp.r_date=myTable.r_date_ may work & be quicker. It may also use an index if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

can try like below, I have did not execute this query just providing logic, if you get any error then revert error so that I can correct the query-

```
SELECT a.r_date, a.deviceid, COUNT(DISTINCT a.timestamp) AS cnt
FROM table1 a 
LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.deviceid=b.deviceid 
WHERE b.value<60 
GROUP BY a.date, a.deviceid 
HAVING cnt>1;
```

Comment: is 'table1 b ON a.licenceid=b.licenceid' correct or should it be 'table1 b ON a.deviceid = b.deviceid'?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a HAVING clause to the solution by fabio_p should do the trick:

```
SELECT  deviceid, r_date, COUNT(DISTINCT time_stamp) AS numRows
FROM myTable
WHERE deviceid NOT IN (SELECT deviceid FROM myTable WHERE value > 60)
GROUP BY deviceid, r_date
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT time_stamp)>y;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  deviceid, r_date, COUNT(DISTINCT time_stamp) AS numRows
FROM myTable
WHERE deviceid NOT IN (SELECT deviceid FROM myTable WHERE value > 60)
GROUP BY deviceid, r_date;
```

should work, tried it on a copy of your db

greetings fabio

Comment: same problem as the last edit of my answer - also needs to return only those with numRows > 1

Comment: add a HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT time_stamp)>y;